# Using Windows Media Player as video fallback for video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video

Getting video to play cross platform using for example video.js is a bit of a fuss. Back in the days when a video should be embedded I use embed Windows media player, which work well out of the box on Windows. Since it's today only old IE on Windows that doesn't support the video tag I experimented with using Windows media player as fallback, and it work very well.

What I wonder here is, why haven't anyone else this solution? Have I missed something? The code is very small, there's no flash files, cross domain issues or need of server to get this working. It just works.

So before I develop this further and add a custom control and subtitles support I wonder what you say.

The code looks like this:

```
<video id="myVideo" style="width:640px; height: 360px;" autoplay data-wimpsource="http://esd.volvocars.com/dc/cdn/video/birds-on-a-wire.mp4">
    <source src="http://esd.volvocars.com/dc/cdn/video/birds-on-a-wire.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://esd.volvocars.com/dc/cdn/video/birds-on-a-wire.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>

function handleVideo(vElementId) {
    var useVideoTag = (typeof(document.createElement('video').canPlayType) != 'undefined'),
        vElement = document.getElementById(vElementId),
        src = vElement.getAttribute('data-wimpsource'),
        playerCode =    '<object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="100%" height="100%">' + 
                        '<param name="filename" value="' + src + '">' + 
                        '   <param name="animationatstart" value="true">' + 
                        '   <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">' + 
                        '   <param name="autostart" value="true">' + 
                        '   <param name="showcontrols" value="false">' + 
                        '   <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">' + 
                        '   <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">' + 
                        '</object>';

    if (!useVideoTag) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.style.width = vElement.style.width;
        newDiv.style.height = vElement.style.height;
        vElement.parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, vElement);
        newDiv.innerHTML = playerCode
    }
}

handleVideo('myVideo');
```

Here's a working demo: 
http://verodella.se/wimpify.html

And here's a JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/arpo/t5Jtx/

Answer (score 0):

Flash has been used for many years as an industry standard for playing video on the web (Youtube did push everyone in that direction). So I guess one part of the answer is in here.

A couple of things to consider:

- Using windows media player will only work if the windows media player is installed on the target device. It is ok on windows machine with Internet explorer I guess but on Firefox or Chrome or Mac the user will need to install a specific plugin. Flash has a much wider adoption rate (95%+) on device that do not support HTML5 video.
- Flash allows to do adaptive bitrate streaming, HD playback with decent performance, DRM and to build custom controls. I am not sure how it goes for a WMP component (Microsoft uses Silverlight for that ... which they have decided to discontinue in favor of HTML5 video).
- [80% of browsers](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/) now support HTML5 video. The main exception is IE8. I guess your effort should go into building a nice HTML5 video experience (especially for mobile) and provide a fallback with maybe lesser options (graceful degradation as it is called).

All in all you could use WMP as a fallback and it will cover most of your users (IE 6,7,8 ...) but it is a better option to opt for flash as a fallback. If you want you can have a look at [Adobe strobe](http://www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html) to get up to speed.

Comment: So why would you want to use Windows media player? Isn't one fallback enough?

Comment: Yes I know Flash is what is used as fallback but as I mentioned it is a bit of a fuss the setup and run. It has cross domain issues must be placed on a server, Flash has to be installed etc. The browsers that needs the fallback solution is IE6-8 and the users of this browsers all sit on Windows and all windows has WMP installed. It's a part of the OS. WMP is a quit advance media player with support for DRM, HD etc. A custom control will be developed in HTML and will be the same for both solutions so if you want to customize it you don't have to do it in both Flash and HTML.

Comment: Using WMP is a valid solution. Though Flash = better coverage and performance/customization as I see it. Others could be able to confirm this. I understand it is a pain to develop twice both Flash and HTML. Most people don't do it on their own (or will offer a lesser experience with either HTML5 or Flash). Have you considered using JW player or Flow Player, they have unified API Flash/HTML5?

Comment: Yes I've been working with both JW Player and video.js (and is a former Flash developer). They do the job but my experience is that that they doesn't work that good when used in a complex CMS system with due to cross domain issues and take some time to setup. Since I'm a lazy developer I like to come up with something that just works in a snap. :)